# Embed songs in html page . once a song is selected though file browser it should appear as thumbnail in html page

Tags: android, jquery, html

I want to Embed songs in html page . once a song is selected though file browser it should appear as thumbnail in html page.
i want function for this in html 5.

I tried with following :

```
function selaudio()
{
    var audiopath=document.getElementById('audioFile').value;

    var audiopath="somefile";
    document.getElementById("audioDiv").innerHTML+="<audio src="+audiopath+" controls></audio><br/>"; 
}
```

this is my code in body :

```
input type="file" name="file" accept="audio/*" onclick="selaudio()" id="audioFile" value="" placeholder="Upload Audio" data-theme="b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JSFiddle, it does exactly what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tv8Cm/48/

The key is to use `URL.createObjectURL`, and not the raw path from the file input.